# Obfuscation in j2me netbeans

Tags: java-me, obfuscation, netbeans-7

i 'm new to obfuscation in netbeans can any one will guide me on how to configure netbeans

for obfuscation & how to obfuscate the j2me package

i used progaurd 4.9 for obfuscation but dont know how to use it
i edited the `build.xml` with progaurd target
then i got error like "Obfuscation failed with error code 1"

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to change build.xml manually. Open project properties, find obfuscation entry and change the value from zero to a higher value.